# check if a pdf file is corrupted using C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

We have an application that generates pdf files, some times for some unknown reason, one of the pdf files gets corrupted, that is it is created corrupted, we need to check if this pdf is corrupted or not before continuing to other pdfs, if it is corrupted we need to create it again.

Thanks

Comment: What does 'corrupted' mean from a technical standpoint? What happens? 0 byte file, only x bytes get copied, jibberish inside, etc.

Comment: To add to that, is the magic number not being set properly?  Is it generating until a point then suddenly you have gibberish?

Comment: No the file is created correctly, with the correct size, but when you try to open it, it gives you a meesge that the file is corrupted

Comment: [Detect if PDF file is correct (header PDF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf)... duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at PDF Parsers and try to use them to detect the corruption.  For example, [ghostscript](http://svn.ghostscript.com/).

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft

In [DotImage Document Imaging](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage), we include some PDF Parsing classes that will throw if the file is corrupt.

If you add our PDF Reader add-on, we will try to rasterize the PDF -- if it's corrupt, that will throw.  If the problem is missing pieces, then you can look for them in the resulting image.

Answer (score -1):

You can check Header PDF like this:

```
public bool IsPDFHeader(string fileName)    
{

    byte[] buffer = null;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

    long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
    //buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
    buffer = br.ReadBytes(5);

    var enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
    var header = enc.GetString(buffer);

    //%PDF−1.0
    // If you are loading it into a long, this is (0x04034b50).
    if (buffer[0] == 0x25 && buffer[1] == 0x50
        && buffer[2] == 0x44 && buffer[3] == 0x46)
    {
        return header.StartsWith("%PDF-");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In a very convoluted way this checks and double-checks whether the file starts with "%PDF-" which are the magic bytes for PDF files. This is no proper corruption test, though, which should test the whole file.

Comment: This answer is just a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf

Comment: I have a corrupted PDF file and this code fails to execute!