# Reading a PDF File using iText5 for .NET

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using C# as programming platform and `iTextSharp` to read PDF content. I have used the below code to read the content but it seems it read per page.

```
        public string ReadPdfFile(object Filename)
        {

            string strText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)Filename);

                for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                    s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                    strText = strText + s;

                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return strText;
        }
```

Can anyone help me on how can I write a code reading pdf content per line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this, use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` instead of the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`
it will add new line characters to the text returned.  Then you can use `strText.Split('\n')` to split your text into a `string[]` and consume it on a per line basis.