# Can't read pdf file

Tags: c#, itext, pdftotext

I'm trying to build an application that can read PDF files. I use this guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET

but do not understand what it means by "file" is the entire url from your computer. Because when I try it as it says that it is in the wrong format.

```
String file = "C:/project/test2.pdf";
// create an instance of the pdfparser class
PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();

// extract the text
String result = pdfParser.ExtractText(file);
```

Wrong message:

> Error 1 No overload for method 'ExtractText' takes 1 arguments

Comment: You missed a `:` after `C` in your path. Still, that's unrelated to your error message.

Comment: Don't helps, but thanks for feedback

Comment: Well, the message is telling you the `ExtractText` method takes more than 1 argument. What parameters does Intellisense say you need to supply?

Comment: public bool ExtractText(string inFileName, string outFileName)

Comment: You might want to follow Ria's answer and use the PDF text parsing functionality already built into iTextSharp (if you are using a current version of it) because the codeproject solution is very naive and ignores much of the PDF specification, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13982550/1729265) discussing "Method 1" from the question which is your `PDFParser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract pdf text into a astring, try to use `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage`, a sampe code:

```
public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    var text = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i want call this function instead?

Comment: U want to read the documentation of the class u downloaded, the function u trying to use requires 2 arguments. Not 1

Comment: in he's example so his take 1 argument, but function can takes two.

Comment: the `ExtractText` method, extract pdf to a **text file**, but  htis method extract to a string.

Comment: is "filename" is fullpath?

Comment: BTW, you should try this without the `String result = pdfParser.ExtractText...` line --- no one could yet explain what it is good for; on the other hand it may break some strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ExtractText` have `two arguments` **one is PDF Source file** and **Second is Text Destination file**

So try like below and your error get resolved:

```
pdfParser.ExtractText(file,Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)+".txt");
```

Comment: wrong message : Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Comment: and add the exampels class.

Comment: Can you try like this `Console.WriteLine(pdfParser.ExtractText(file,Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)+".txt").ToString());` and tell us what message you got...

Comment: @MaxTorstensson DarkBee already posted the method signature `public bool ExtractText(string inFileName, string outFileName)` --- so why do you try to assign `String result = pdfParser.ExtractText(...)`??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should correctly specify path.
You can download test project from the link to codeproject which you have posted.

And you should use it like that:

```
string sourceFile =  "C:\\Folder\\File.pdf";
string outputFile =  "C:\\Folder\\File2.txt"

PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();
pdfParser.ExtractText(sourceFile, outputFile);
```

UPD:
You use it WRONG (and you certainly get your error: cannot implicitly convert bool to string):

```
string result = pdfParser.ExtractText(sourceFile, outputFile);
```

RIGHT WAY IS:

```
pdfParser.ExtractText(sourceFile, outputFile);
```

Comment: WRONG : wrong message : Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Comment: 1. Max, as far as I can see in this version of library there are no method ExtractText that use only one argument, so you should use output file.

Comment: thanks for posting on pastebin.
You could not use it like string result = pdfParser(file, output);
Delete all from the left from pdfParser.

Comment: i tried it but i found this wrong message : WRONG : wrong message : Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Comment: you get this error because you call pdfParser (file, output) and trying to attach it to string result. delete "string result ="

Comment: Thank you. It went in but gets it out in very strange encodning unfortunately.

Comment: That's strange. Try to change encoding of the file to UTF-8, for example.

Comment: @MaxTorstensson As mentioned above, PDFParser is a very naive implementation of a PDF text parser.

Comment: @MaxTorstensson I completely agree with mkl, that codeproject lib is a rubbish, you better use his advice.

Comment: @Fyodor Not that strange if you look at the `PDFParser` code --- it makes many assumptions which happen to be (mostly) true only in simply built PDFs for Western languages, foremost English.

Comment: @mkl, thanks a lot!
I think author of this project should add [your useful comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977738/which-is-the-right-method-to-text-extraction-strategy/13982550#13982550) to the description at codeproject. :)