# How-To: Validate a FileStream is a valid PDF document with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, validation, pdf, filestream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if PDF file is correct (header PDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf)

I want to validate that the data in a `FileStream` instance represents a valid PDF document.  Specifically, I need to know that Adobe Reader will be able to successfully open the file.

Can anyone recommend an open source library or best practice for this task?

Comment: Write it to a file, and try to open using the default application. Don't know what to do when there is no application associated with `.pdf` though :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible other than opening it up with adobe reader. I'm interested to see if there is a another way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257743/2778651  is the answer .  First 4 bytes  should give the answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) , it should give you what you need.

EDIT:

I know it's bad practice to use exceptions to control flow, but you could do this:

```
public bool IsValidPdf(string fileName)
{
   try
   {
      new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fileName);
      return true;
   }
   catch (iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to accomplish this with iTextSharp?  It turned up in my research, but [this blog](http://jeffgermain.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/validating-pdf-documents/) said that iTextSharp has no such feature

Comment: I just assumed it did, I take a look, been a while since I used it..

Answer (score -2):

Open the file in memory and check if the first line is something like:

```
%PDF-1.5
```

or

```
%PDF-1.4
```

or simple %PDF string.

it's not very secure but worked for me.

Comment: Most likely downvoted due to the fact that question is whether the filestream is a PDF not thinks it is a PDF.  The existence of that first line does not guarantee that it is a PDF.