# Does endsWith consider a path's file extension, and is this a security vulnerability?

Tags: java, security

When I call `endsWith(".pdf")`, would this open malware.pdf.exe or just malware.pdf?

```
String sFileName = request.getParameter("fName");
if (sFileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
// open file
else
// don’t open the file
```

Comment: Please add a language tag to the question. (I'm assuming this is Java?)

Comment: Most likely, `endsWith` means "ends with". The .pdf in malware is not at the end.

Comment: it doesnt matter what language it is. its just a general security issue. but its obviously in java....

Comment: most likely or 100% sure. malware.pdf is the name that is an executable. malware is the name that is a pdf file. it doesnt necessarily means that it ends in .pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.endsWith` works as documented. However, there are a couple of obvious problems here.

- A NUL character `\0` will typically terminate the string as far as the OS file API is concerned (because it'll be using C strings).
- If served up, may lose content by extension, possibly being macgiced to a different type.
- It's generally dangerous to run PDFs downloaded from the internet from the local filesystem. (Chrome warns of this and see Billy Rios on [Content Smuggling](http://xs-sniper.com/blog/2012/10/11/content-smuggling/)).

Answer (score 1):

`.endsWith("string")` will perform as you intend. However, that doesn't mean that the file is actually a pdf. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf) or others for more information on how to check the header.