# How to determine if the uploaded file on my server is a pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

i need to determine if the uploaded file on my server is pdf or not?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? What's not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check the extension of the file :)
And you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf).

> 1. You may simply try to load PDF file with one of such libraries. [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) will be a good choice.
> 2. In accordance with PDF reference the header of PDF file has usually form %PDF−1.X (where X is a number, for the present from 0 to 7).
>
> E.g. the header may be appeared somewhere within the first 1024 bytes of the file or be in the form %!PS−Adobe−N.n PDF−M.m

Answer (score 2):

You can check the file type on the server side:

```
if (string.Equals(fileExt, ".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {...}
```

This counteracts input such as "pdf2", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file extension is .pdf

You can do this during upload by using the following code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="pdfUpload" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateFilePDF"
      ErrorMessage="Please select valid pdf document"></asp:CustomValidator>

function ValidateFilePDF(Source, args) {
    var fuData = document.getElementById('<%= yourFileUploadInputBoxID.ClientID %>');
    var FileUploadPath = fuData.value;

    if (FileUploadPath == '') {

       args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
       var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

       if (Extension == "pdf" {
           args.IsValid = true; 
       }
       else {
           args.IsValid = false;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: User can change extension of the file.