# How to check a rar file is a true rar file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In order to prevent hacker uploading forged rar file  Trojan Horses

How to check a rar file is a true rar file,not a forged file in asp.net?Thank you very much!

Sorry for my explain,me means:

Assume that there is a `111.txt` file ,change the file suffix to rar .So the file name is `111.rar` now .How to check this file not a true rar file ?

Comment: Please give more explanation about your task. There's no such thing as a true rar file, and forgery has a very broad definition

Comment: In order to prevent hacker uploading forged rar file trojan .

Comment: Checking if a file is a trojan is a multi million dollar industry... Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you can do

1. checking the header of the given file and matching that with proven rar file header.
2. Un rar(decompress th given file) and if it success then you can be sure that the given file is valid rar.(http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rar-dotnet.asp)

I would like to recommend you the first method.

Howerver if you are conserned about torjan viruses then try scanning the file with antivirus
see this-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121740/asp-net-solution-for-file-upload-virus-scanning

Comment: @Ratna-thanks for your reply.But what is the true rar file header?

Comment: create some rar files, then open them in binary mode, you will find that some data to certain length are always same(header). This data is added by winrar and will always be same in atleast same version rar. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ratna-Give some examples will appreciate!

Comment: I can give you an example for exe files, the exe files   first two bytes is always "MZ".bool CheckIsExecutable(string filePath)
{
    var firstBytes = new byte[2];
    using(var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        fileStream.Read(firstBytes, 0, 2);
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(firstBytes) == "MZ";
} see here http://forums.asp.net/p/1906504/5397338.aspx?Re+File+Upload+Type+Check+Headers

Comment: Another example with pdf files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf