# Converting document from base 64 giving error

Tags: c#, base64, decoding

For my project user send me a base64 encoded code. I need to convert into pdf document.

I am using the below code for the same.

```
string AsBase64String = "base64code";
byte[] tempBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(AsBase64String);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\d\hh.pdf", tempBytes);
```

and this is working successfully but in some cases it is generating the pdf. When opening the pdf it is showing it is not valid format.

I use the same code in the below online website

```
http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html
```

Pasted the code and decode it and saved as a file and try to open in pdf. It gave the same error. Then I open the file in notepad and copy the code inside and decode it in the above website again. Then save it as file. When i open the second file it opened successfully.

Steps I done

1. Took the base64 code from client and decode it using the website.
2. took the decoded code and decoded it again
3. then saved the code and open it and it open successfully.

but most of the cases first decode itself open successfully in pdf. Rare cases it needed two time decoding.

What may be the trick happening here. I am new to this base64 decoding. Please show some light on this issue

Comment: Well, obviously the person who sent you the file made a mistake and encoded it twice. Fix that, and your problem goes away. Also, why are you transmitting files encoded to base64? I hope you're not doing it for security reasons...

Comment: @Rob agree to your point. but this is coming from numerous person..is there any method to identify how many times it is encoded from the string we are receiving?

Comment: No, not really. You'd have the read the spec for PDF and inspect the headers of the file to determine whether or not it's a valid PDF file. Or, use a library to do it. Still, the problem is on the other end, so the problem should be fixed there. What if they encode it 100 times? Would you okay continually decoding it until you find a valid pdf file (which might not actually exist?). Seems like an easy way to DOS the service

Comment: @Rob we are transmitting the files encoded to base64 bcos its the standard xml protocol follow by the project..its passing through xml schema

Comment: @rob i tried to read the header to understand the file format..but the problem is user is not saving that info at header section too :(

Comment: I meant the header information in the file, not the web request. Also, see [here - Detect if PDF file is correct (header PDF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf)

Comment: @Rob thanks..using ITextLibrary i am able to check valid pdf..but next pblm is if it fail how i makeup the second string from the current base64 to make the correct pdf

Comment: You'd simply decode the resulting string. Look up `C# convert byte[] to string` and if you're still stuck, post a new question (but really, you should find an answer to it throughout SO - there are lots of solutions).

Comment: @Rob what is wanted is bas64->base64->pdf..sorry if its confusing

Comment: Yes - 1. You'd load the original file into a string. 2. You decode the string. 3. You've got a `byte[]`. 4 Check for PDF. 5 Not valid? Convert the `byte[]` to `string`. Go back to step 2. The only thing missing here is converting `byte[]` to `string`

Comment: @Rob if u can put it as answer i can mark it..it solved my issue..thanks a lot