# pdf not showing in ashx when response content type is pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have an application that shows pdf files on browser, it works fine with most files
but some give me an error, I commented the line that specifies the content type and it worked but I don't know why and I can't check every pdf file because there are millions. pdf files are not corrupted.

Can somebody explain why this works?

```
        HttpContext context
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        //If I include this line some pdfs are not shown, shows message file does not begin with ' pdf-'
        //context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(document);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
```

Comment: I would start by adding `context.Response.Clear()` at the very beginning of this snippet, chances are you already have part of your answer in the response stream. Report back if this helps.

Comment: does this only happen with a particular browser? have you tried specifying the length of the file in the headers?

Comment: @derloopkat it works with IE but not with firefox, so I added again the line because I don't know which browser the user is going to use

Comment: do you see an error in console or network tab?

Comment: @derloopkat I did't not check the browser console, it shows the following error message:                                                                                                           Invalid or corrupted PDF file.
PDF.js v1.9.583 (build: d7b37ae7)
Message: Invalid PDF structure

Comment: I've tested your code and the handler worked fine in latest versions of Firefox, IE, Opera, Chrome. Perhaps it's a problem with the Pdf itself or your Firefox. Try adding information about the size of the file in response headers. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now the error message, It means your pdf file is not well formed, no pdf viewer will render it,  So I used the code posted by @Kiquenet in this thread to validate if it starts with pdf:

[Detect if PDF file is correct (header PDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108201/detect-if-pdf-file-is-correct-header-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It worked fine.